# Ubuntu preseed expert_recipe priority/max size don't translate into correct result

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm

Despite reading through the various posts and answers online, it's still very unclear to me how the `<minimal size> <priority> <maximal size>` parameters of `partman-auto/expert_recipe` actually translate into determination of the end disk space allocated.

In the example below, the underlying disk has 64G of space, of which allocations *should* be:

- 1G to `/boot`
- 8G to `/home`
- 10G to `/usr`
- and so on (see the full specification in MiB below from `preseed/ubuntu-server-unattended.seed`)

Actual result are consistently off by several hundred MB:

[image]

I have seen and read the following, and none of them, in my opinion, seem to agree or clarify in plain wording how the `priority` field actually behaves and translates into the final sizes.

- https://secopsmonkey.com/custom-partioning-using-preseed.html
- https://cptyesterday.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/notes-on-using-expert_recipe-in-debianubuntu-preseed-files/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/953322/preseed-automatic-partitioning
- https://serverfault.com/questions/722021/preseeding-debian-install-efi?noredirect=1&lq=1
- https://serverfault.com/questions/550072/preseeding-ubuntu-partman-recipe-using-lvm-and-raid?rq=1
- https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debian-installer/-/blob/buster/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt

In this example, the sum of the `<max>` values don't even come anywhere close to the constraint of 64GB.  So **what specifically would I need to set each `<priority>` value to in order to get actual sizes aligned with the `<max>` field?**

Exact specification in `preseed/ubuntu-server-unattended.seed`:

```
d-i    partman-auto/method                  string lvm
d-i    partman/default_filesystem           string ext4
d-i    partman-auto/choose_recipe    select boot-root
d-i    partman-auto/expert_recipe    string \
    boot-root ::                            \
        500 1000 1000 ext2                  \
            $primary{ }                     \
            $bootable{ }                    \
            method{ format }                \
            format{ }                       \
            use_filesystem{ }               \
            filesystem{ ext2 }              \
            label{ boot }                   \
            mountpoint{ /boot }             \
            .                               \
        4096 8192 8192 $default_filesystem    \
            $lvmok{ }                       \
            lv_name{ RootVol }      \
            method{ format }                \
            format{ }                       \
            use_filesystem{ }               \
            mountpoint{ / }   \
            $default_filesystem{ }          \
            options/defaults{ defaults }    \
            options/discard{ discard }    \
            options/iversion{ iversion }    \
            .         \
        1024 4096 4096 $default_filesystem    \
            $lvmok{ }                       \
            lv_name{ HomeVol }      \
            method{ format }                \
            format{ }                       \
            use_filesystem{ }               \
            mountpoint{ /home }   \
            $default_filesystem{ }          \
            options/defaults{ defaults }    \
            options/nosuid{ nosuid }    \
            options/nodev{ nodev }    \
            .         \
        8192 10240 10240 $default_filesystem    \
            $lvmok{ }                       \
            lv_name{ UsrVol }      \
            method{ format }                \
            format{ }                       \
            use_filesystem{ }               \
            mountpoint{ /usr }   \
            $default_filesystem{ }          \
            options/defaults{ defaults }    \
            options/nodev{ nodev }    \
            .         \
        2048 4096 4096 $default_filesystem    \
            $lvmok{ }                       \
            lv_name{ VarLogAuditVol }      \
            method{ format }                \
            format{ }                       \
            use_filesystem{ }               \
            mountpoint{ /var/log/audit }   \
            $default_filesystem{ }          \
            options/defaults{ defaults }    \
            options/nodev{ nodev }    \
            options/nosuid{ nosuid }    \
            .         \
        2048 4096 4096 $default_filesystem    \
            $lvmok{ }                       \
            lv_name{ VarLogVol }      \
            method{ format }                \
            format{ }                       \
            use_filesystem{ }               \
            mountpoint{ /var/log }   \
            $default_filesystem{ }          \
            options/defaults{ defaults }    \
            options/nodev{ nodev }    \
            options/nosuid{ nosuid }    \
            .         \
        2048 8192 -1 $default_filesystem    \
            $lvmok{ }                       \
            lv_name{ VarVol }      \
            method{ format }                \
            format{ }                       \
            use_filesystem{ }               \
            mountpoint{ /var }   \
            $default_filesystem{ }          \
            options/defaults{ defaults }    \
            options/nodev{ nodev }    \
            options/nosuid{ nosuid }    \
            .
```

From the [spec](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debian-installer/-/blob/buster/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt):

> `<limits>::=<minimal size>_<priority>_<maximal size>_<parted fs>`
>
> `<minimal size>` is the minimal allowed size of the partition in
> megabytes.  It is rounded to cylinder size, so if you make `<minimal size>` to be 20 MB and the cylinder size is 12MB, then it is possible
> for the partition to be only 12MB.  These sizes may also be given as
> a percentage, which makes the size be that percentage of the system's
> total RAM, or (as of partman-auto 87) as a number plus a percentage
> (e.g. "2000+50%"), which makes the size be that number plus that
> percentage of the system's total RAM.
>
> `<priority>` is some size usually between `<minimal size>` and `<maximal size>`.  It determines the priority of this partition in the contest
> with the other partitions for size.  Notice that if  is too
> small (relative to the priority of the other partitions) then this
> partition will have size close to .  That's why it is
> recommended to give small partitions a `<priority>` larger than their
> `<maximal size>`.
>
> `<maximal size>` is the maximal size for the partition, i.e. a limit
> size such that there is no sense to make this partition larger.
> The special value "-1" is used to indicate unlimited partition size.

**The part where the spec seems to break down is [here](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debian-installer/-/blob/buster/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt)**:

```
x = min[i] + (free_space - minsum) * factor[i] / factsum;
if (x > max[i])
    x = max[i];
```

This implies each `x` should have a ceiling at `max[i]` if the disk space will allow it. In this case, that should hold true, since there is more than enough residual space even when all `max` are summed. So what gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what specifically would I need to set each  value to in order to get actual sizes aligned with the  field?

Your partitions are aligned to the `<max>` field.  The tools just use different units.  Partman uses MB.  `lsblk` is using MiB and GiB.  For example, your `/boot` partition is defined with a max of `1000`.  This is `1000 MB`, which is equal to `953 MiB`.

The others are aligned too

- 1000 MB == 953.674 MiB
- 8192 MB == 7.629395 GiB
- 4096 MB == 3.814697 GiB
- 10240 MB == 9.5367432 GiB

**See also**

- https://www.gbmb.org/mb-to-mib
- https://www.majordifferences.com/2018/03/differences-between-megabyte-and.html
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=913431 (partman-base: Add support for kiB, MiB)

Comment: Thanks very much, this got me to the target MiB/GiB values precisely using 'translated' values such 4295/8590 etc in the partman recipe. Appreciate especially you digging up the final link there.